# jQuery UI tooltips showing at the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery-ui-tooltip

In my project I am using jQuery UI 1.10.2 to display tooltips for links on the page. However, when I hover over any links, the tooltip displays at the bottom of the page underneath the content area rather than right below the link.

Upon closer examination, I found that when hovering over a tooltip item, the "top" style is not set for the ui-tooltip div for some reason.

```
$(document).tooltip({ 
  content: function() { 
    return $(this).attr('title'); 
  }
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas about why it would be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully solved this issue. As it turns out, I had been including the jquery.dimensions plugin in my sources, and somehow it was conflicting with my jquery-ui-1.10.2 include and causing the tooltips to display *below* all of my content. Removing the include for jquery.dimensions solved the problem.

Hopefully this can help someone else who may have the same issue in the future.